# Get content between comments

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Hopefully not too tricky this one...

I am trying to get just the context between the `<!-- itemtemplate -->` comments using javascript (with the jQuery plugin). The result must exclude the comments though.  In this case the parent is a table, but it can be anything such as a div

Table

```
<table id="lvList" class="grid1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name </th>
        <th>Number </th>
        <th>Type </th>
        <th>Account Manager </th>
    </tr>
    <!-- itemtemplate -->
    <tr>
        <td><boundfield output="hyperlink" datafield="name" dataurlfields="id" dataurlformat="details/?id={0}" /></td>
        <td><boundfield output="string" datafield="id" /></td>
        <td><boundfield output="string" datafield="type" /></td>
        <td><boundfield output="string" datafield="accmgr" /></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- itemtemplate -->
</table>
```

Div

```
<div id="lvList">
  <!-- itemtemplate -->
     something something something
     <boundfield output="string" datafield="id" />
  <!-- itemtemplate -->
</div>
```

---

**Thanks to Felix for the idea**

```
function GetTemplate(root, name) {
    var output = "";
    var record = false;
    function iterate(node) {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.trim() === "") continue;

            if (child.nodeType === 8 && child.nodeValue.trim() === name) {
                if (!record) { record = true; continue; }
                else { break; }
            }

            if (record)
                output += outerHTML(child);
            else {
                if (child.hasChildNodes)
                    iterate(child);
            }
        }
    }
    iterate(root);
    return output;
};
function ClearTemplate (root, name) {
    var record = false;
    function iterate(node) {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType === 8 && child.nodeValue.trim() === name) {
                if (!record) { record = true; continue; }
                else { break; }
            }
            if (record)
                node.removeChild(child);
            else {
                if (child.hasChildNodes)
                    iterate(child);
            }
        }
    }
    iterate(root);
};
function InsertInto (root, name, items) {
    function iterate(node) {
        var children = node.childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            var child = children[i];
            if (child.nodeType === 3 && child.nodeValue.trim() === "") continue;
            if (child.nodeType === 8 && child.nodeValue.trim() === name) {
                for (var n = items.length - 1; n >= 0; n--)
                    child.parentNode.insertBefore(items[n], child.nextSibling);
                break;
            }
            if (child.hasChildNodes)
                iterate(child);
        }
    }
    iterate(root);
};
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+|(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+$/g, "");
};
function outerHTML(node) {
    return node.outerHTML || 
            (function (n) {
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.appendChild(n.cloneNode(true));
                return div.innerHTML;
            })(node);
};
```

Comment: why don't you use `jQuery.tmpl()` plugin?

Comment: is it always the second TR that you're trying to get?

Comment: This looks like a terrible home-brew of a template language. If you can, you should use jQuery Template or something similar.

Comment: @Robert will look into tmpl now but no, not always the 2nd tr

Comment: How do you get this content: it's a DOM element's or string or response of xmlhttprequest?

Comment: jquery template is cool but I still have to pass the markup to it, which means i still have to get the context between the comments.. i like it going forward though

Comment: @Andrew, its static content on an html page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither regex nor jQuery: The idea is to iterate over all child nodes and check whether the node is a comment node and if yes, whether it contains a certain string, e.g. `itemtemplate`.

```
function extract(node, needle) {
    var children = node.childNodes,
        record = false,
        container = document.createDocumentFragment();

    for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
        var child = children[i];

        if(child.nodeType === 8 && child.nodeValue === needle) {
            record = !record;
            continue;
        }   

        if(record) {
            container.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
        }       
    }
    return container;
}
```

Usage:

```
var nodes = extract(someParent, ' itemtemplate ');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ur7ah/1/)

I don't know whether this is the best solution for you situation, you don't give any information about the context.

Comment: this is great assuming those comments are the only ones within the parent.  if I add <!-- some comment --> elsewhere, wouldnt this then fail?

Comment: @Christian: No, it compares the text of the comment against what you pass a second parameter. I added an example.

Comment: just picked up on that, sorry 5am start today :)

Comment: just changed your code a bit, as shown above, but otherwise perfect, thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML data (as HTML is a type of) using regular expressions is bound to fail.
I suggest you use a tool specifically designed for parsing XML. In javascript, DOMParser can be used for this.

[Link to w3schools for using this.](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)

Comment: `DOMParser()` isn't fully cross browser.  And HTML is not a type of XML - they're both derivatives of SGML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var result = '<div id="lvList"><!-- itemtemplate -->something something 
something<boundfield output="string" datafield="id" /><!-- itemtemplate --></div>'
.split(/<!--\s*itemtemplate\s*-->/)
```

result[1] will have the desired text you want.

Comment: Too bad, what can i say :) May be you can try this cross browser compatible split given here http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split