# jQuery tmpl plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

The most annoying thing about tmpl is that you cant replace ${n} inside <> such as

```
<a href="details/?id=${id}">${name}</a>
```

the ${id} wouldnt get replaced..

Any ideas how to do that without having to use the `<script>` tags, cause that isnt a good way to do it.

or even how to check a checkbox..

My template looks like this

```
<table id="lvList" class="grid1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Account Manager</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- itemtemplate -->
    <tr>
        <td>{{html $item.href('details/?id=$id')}}</td>
        <td>${id}</td>
        <td>${type}</td>
        <td>${accmgr}</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- itemtemplate -->
</table>
```

if you want to know how I got the template from the table, you can see this post
[ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594661/get-content-between-comments/7594793#7594793)

Using that template, this is what I came up with

```
var items = $.tmpl(this.itemtemplate, data, {
    href: function (url) {
        for (i in this.data)
        { url = url.replace("$" + i, this.data[i]); }
        return "<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + this.data["name"] + "</a>";
    }
});
```

Comment: Why isn't using script tags a good idea?

Comment: I figured out a method. see my question

Comment: I'm still curious why using script tags for your templates isn't a good idea.

Comment: Im sure its possible, it just seems a bit silly to add script tags in the middle of a table.  Feels like a developers hack!

Comment: It is a hack, but it works and is easy.

Comment: ok... forget what ive been saying.. using scripts was easy enough :)