# how to extract content between html comments in java

Tags: java, html

i have html snippet which will have annotations in the comments like   and need to extract content between the comments using java . The problem is ther can be multiple annotations to look for. How will i parse each html tag in java

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <!--@Required-->
        <script src="req.js"></script>
        <!--@START-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="date.css">
        <!--@END-->
    </head>
```

Comment: You can try using a Regular Expression to find the comments and remove them.

Comment: so what would the reg ex be like, i dont need to remove the comments but i need the content within the "@Start" and "@End"

Comment: similar to this thread but this is done in javascript where it is easier to parse teh dom. i need to do this in java  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594661/get-content-between-comments

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but comments are meant to be for helping....
try something like this???

```
<tab/*Comment Here*/>Ok</tab>
```

Clarify your question, this is my answer.

Comment: no, the snippet i posted is exactly what i need to extract between. basically i need to extract between the comments but all  the comments will have special annotions i.e they start with <!--@ and end with -->

Answer (score 0):

There are HTML parsers available.

1. [Java source.net](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers)
2. [Java sourceforge.net](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/#extraction)
   Summary, you have to understand that the tags have values like script and link. They will be the node keys. You'll find code samples in their site and elsewhere, if u Google it.

Comment: similar to this thread but this is done in javascript where it is easier to parse teh dom. i need to do this in java stackoverflow.com/questions/7594661/…